# Background work thread for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, event-handling

I'd like to add something like a "background" thread to a rails application. I need to check emails from time to time (let's say every 10 minutes) and then do something according to the emails. This should work the same way as the bug trackers work, you can reply to an email you got from the bug tracker, and it will take the email and add it to the ticket.

Is there any easy way of running something like this in the background? I don't want to use cron, or any system tools, just pure ruby. I start application, and I shouldn't care of anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EventMachine have [PeriodicTimer](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/PeriodicTimer.html)

```
 n = 0
 timer = EventMachine::PeriodicTimer.new(5) do
   puts "the time is #{Time.now}"
   timer.cancel if (n+=1) > 5
 end
```

[rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) is a tool of cron-like write in pure Ruby base EventMachine.

Comment: rufus-scheduler is no longer based on EventMachine.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of potential problems with the accepted answer worth pointing out.

First, `PeriodicTimer` reschedules itself for execution using tail recursion, i.e., by calling `EventMachine.add_timer` after executing its block. Unfortunately, the code does not use `begin-ensure-end` which means that if there is an exception in your code the timer will stop. See [GH#454](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/454).

Second, there is the issue of `EventMachine`'s reactor loop running in a single thread as a singleton. If you start a `PeriodicTimer` and perform slow email operations in its block you will block the reactor loop which other code may depend on. A better approach is to push the email gathering work to a separate thread using `EventMachine::Deferrable`. See [this post](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/10/01/an-introduction-to-eventmachine-and-how-to-avoid-callback-spaghetti/) for an example.

Last but not least you should run `EventMachine` on a separate thread if its reactor is not running yet but you should "schedule" your work on the reactor's thread if it is already running.

Putting this together you have something along the lines of:

```rb
def check_email
  timer = EM::PeriodicTimer.new(10.minutes) do
    begin
      DefferableEmailChecker.new.errback do |error|
        # handle error
        # note that this code will run OUTSIDE the
        # periodic timer block
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      # even with a Deferable this is good practice
      # if you want to cancel, use timer.cancel
    end
  end
end

if EM.reactor_running?
  EM.schedule do
    check_email
  end
else
  Thread.new do
    EM.run do
      check_email
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Daemon-Kit](https://github.com/kennethkalmer/daemon-kit).  It's allows you to create Ruby Daemons in a framework with similar conventions to Rails' projects.  We use it to monitor and perform a variety of background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) in my project.

> Delayed_job (or DJ) encapsulates the common pattern of asynchronously executing longer tasks in the background.